# Unmatch escaped braces

Tags: python, python-re

Which regular expression can I use to find all `}`, all while excluding escaped `\}`?
I.e. how do I get as only match:

```
{Hello \} world}
               ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern should achieve your goal:

```
(?<!\\)\}
```

The pattern you're looking for is `(?<!...)`:

> Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion.

In contrast to Amirhossein Kiani's suggestion, the match does not include the preceding character, but only the closing bracket. To illustrate:

```
{Hello \} world}
               ^ with negative lookbehind
{Hello \} world}
              ^^ with Amirhossein Kiani's suggestion
```

Note: When working with regular expressions in Python, please study [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Many simple questions like this could be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! A small precision: I don't think that `}` has to be escaped

Answer (score 1):

You can try the pattern below:

```
[^\\](?P<bracket>})
```

Note that, this will select all `}` that do not have a `\` before them, but any other character will be selected. You can try`.group` function giving `bracket` as an argument to select the bracket.

To have a better understanding, take a look at [this link](https://regex101.com/r/5MNaR6/1)

##### Update

Personally speaking, I prefer Green绿色's answer since it just selects the desired bracket.